# How to save contacts in an address book and list them?

Tags: c#, exception

I am working on making an address book in C# 2008. I need to be able to save the contacts and then later display them when the user asked for it. I also need to handle an exception when someone enters an unknown color when writing the person's favorite color.
This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab02
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's name:");
            contact.Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's e-mail address:");
            contact.Email = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's favorite color:");
            string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
            contact.Favoritecolor = (System.Drawing.KnownColor)(Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor), tempColor));
            try
            {

            }
            catch 
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is an unknown color. Please enter a known color");
            } 
        }
        class Color
        {
            enum clr
            // This is a list of colors for the user to pick from.
            {
                Red,
                Green,
                Blue,
                Yellow,
                Purple,
                Brown,
                Black,
                Crimson,
                White,
                Turqoise,
                Orange,
                Cyan,
                Pink,
                Gold,
                Silver,
                Bronze,
                Gray,
                Indigo,
                Rust
            }
        }
    }
        class Contact
        {
            //This string represents the person's Name.
            public string Name { get; set; }

            //This string represents the person's Email.
            public string Email { get; set; }

            public System.Drawing.KnownColor Favoritecolor 
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Unless you pick a part of this (i.e. saving the contact, throwing the exception, etc) and rephrase the question to ask about that particular part, this is gonna get closed.

Comment: This is your third question on the same subject today. This isn't really what StackOverflow is intended for .. stick to editing a single question -- and at least mark the previous ones as answered, if they helped you!

Comment: Your namespace says Lab02. Are you trying to get us to help you with your homework?

Comment: Well where do you want to save your contacts: XML, text, database?

Comment: Ben M, ok I will. sorry I'm new to this site

Comment: I did retag it as homework earlier, it somehow got untagged. I've retagged it again.

Comment: You need to read your assignment for hints about where/how to store the contacts. Then have a go at doing it yourself, and if you get stuck, ask a **specific** question here.

Comment: And somehow, once again, the homework tag has disappeared. The only decent tag there just now is "C#" and perhaps "saving". Going to retag again! (What was the definition of madness again?)

Comment: If you're not going to answer, don't leave comments. And please don't change the tags. I needs to be related to the code not what it is for.

Comment: The "Homework" tag is a valid and expected tag if the question is homework related.

Comment: Jeff, if you're new to the site, read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq at the top of each page. And you should reconsider whether the "new guy" should be removing the tags put there by the "old-timers".

Comment: Jeff: Please don't ask duplicate questions, and please stop editing the tags.  If this post gets flagged for moderator attention again, I'm going to have to lock it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not list all colors that the user can pick, with the Enum Value, then ask them to enter a number, try and convert it to an enum,then store it. If it fails to convert, let them know it's invalid.

Here's a little snippet to help. You'll need to make your enum public however.

```
Console.WriteLine("Here are a list of colors:");

foreach(Color.clr item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color.clr)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}",(int)item,item.ToString()));
}
Console.WriteLine("Please choose your color");
string colorInput = Console.ReadLine();
int colorValue = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(colorInput, out colorValue))
{
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is not a valid number",colorInput));
        return;
}

// This will give an error if they've typed a number that wasn't listed
// So need to add a bit of checking here
Color.clr tempColor = (Color.clr)colorValue;

// Your code here
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i put it in at the top I get this error: "A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods" Where should I put this snippet?

Comment: This should be in Main() routine.

Comment: This is where you would ask for the color, I'll add a little bit more

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Reflection:

```
    public static class ColorInfo
    {
        private static readonly PropertyInfo[] PropertiesInfo;

        static ColorInfo()
        {
            PropertiesInfo = typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        }

        public static bool TryGetKnownColorFromString(string colorName, out KnownColor knowColor)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(colorName))//if wrong color name
            {
                knowColor = KnownColor.ActiveBorder;
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in PropertiesInfo)
                {
                    if (property.Name.Equals(colorName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        knowColor = ((Color)property.GetValue(null, null)).ToKnownColor();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //catch GetValue & Equals methods exceptions
                if (!(exc is ArgumentException || exc is TargetException ||
                    exc is TargetParameterCountException ||
                    exc is MethodAccessException ||
                    exc is TargetInvocationException))
                {
                    //throw exc; //We don't want to lose information from StackTrace
                    throw; 
                }
            }
            knowColor = KnownColor.ActiveBorder;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Simply test:

```
        string[] colors = { "reD", "AzUre", "Blue", "BlueViollet" };
        KnownColor knowColor;
        foreach (String color in colors)
        {
            if (ColorInfo.TryGetKnownColorFromString(color, out knowColor))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(knowColor.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Color: {0} - not found !", color);
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
Red
Azure
Blue
Color: BlueViollet - not found !
```

Helpfull usings:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: If you really must rethrow from within an exception then use throw. Do not throw exc because it will reset the stack trace details and you lose where the original came from.

Answer (score 1):

are you going to display them in the console app, Form App, does it need to persist the data or just hold in memory for the lifetime of the app, is your class "Contact" serializable

For simplicity sake and since this is homework make your class Contact Serializable

```
[Serializable]
public class Contact
{}
```

and use Binary serialization, I'm not going to write it all here but its fairlysimple look up Binary serialization and binaryformaters which can write a stream to disk for each contact or a list of contacts if you like.
then if this is in the console app make a readline that accepts a "List" command and hits a method that iterates them and displays the properties for each contact.

Thats as far as I will go for writing your homework unless you pay me

Comment: It needs to persist the data and display it in the app

Comment: Persist them where? Go ask the teacher where he wants them. You can then ask a better question.

Comment: In a .dll file located in the folder

Comment: The teacher does **not** want the addresses persisted in a DLL. Do you even _have_ the assignment with you?

Answer (score 0):

The parsing gets moved into the try block, the catch block (which catches the exception) tells the user they need to enter something known. The finally block isn't required, so was removed:

```
try
{
    contact.Favoritecolor = (System.Drawing.KnownColor)(Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor), tempColor));
}
catch(ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is an unknown color. Please enter a known color");
}
```

The next part is that you need a loop until a valid colour has been entered

```
bool isValidColour = false;
while (!isValidColour)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's favorite color:");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        contact.Favoritecolor = (System.Drawing.KnownColor)(Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor), tempColor));
    isValidColour = true;
    }
    catch(ArgumentException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an unknown color. Please enter a known color");
    }
}
```

The above will keep looping around until a valid colour is entered.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Only trying to protect newby developers from learning bad habits from script kiddies.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this line:

```
   contact.Favoritecolor = (System.Drawing.KnownColor)(Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor), tempColor));
```

Is where you are taking the value of color entered by the user, and parsing it into a known color, correct?

Seems like thats where you might run into problems. I'd see what type of exceptions can be thrown with that line, and properly handle them.

What happens if someone enters "rED" in the commandline? Should that thrown an exception? In your code example, will it throw an exception?

Additionally, you have a custom Color Class, with an enum type called "clr", but in your code, you're parsing your enum to the System.Drawing.KnownColor type. I would nix the custom class and use the built in type.